# Is it possible to make Object.prototype Null?

Tags: javascript

I was checking some JS library code and got to know that they are using prototype function From the main Object like **`Object.prototype.toString.call(a, this)`** (here a is an object). So Is it possible to assign `null` in main Object prototype, like `Object.prototype = null`?

Comment: You can create objects with prototype assigned to null. `var obj = Object.create(null);`. It's useful when iterating these objects without making `.hasOwnProperty()` checks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object.prototype is [not writable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype). So no. In fact none of the built-in prototypes are writable.

You can try it right here:

```js
console.log(typeof Object.prototype.toString); //"function"
Object.prototype = null;
console.log(typeof Object.prototype.toString); //not nullified - still "function"

console.log(typeof String.prototype.substring); //"function"
String.prototype = null;
console.log(typeof String.prototype.substring); //same
```

Comment: @Vassan Thanks for the quick response. But why prototype is null when we create the object with Object.create(Null)?

Comment: That's a different usecase. You're explicitly creating a new object with a null prototype (what you pass as argument is set as `__proto__` of the created instance). It's different from making the prototype field of the builtin Object type itself as null (which isn't possible).

Comment: @Shubham `Object.create(null)` is a special case and objects created in this manner won't have accesss to the `__proto__` getter/setter which is at the `Object.prototype`. I don't think you can implement `Object.create(null)` yourself eg polyfill etc...